# Update a related model field based on another field

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates, django-views, django-queryset

I have 2 model choice field Category and Sub Category. Sub Category is based on Category.

I have to fill the sub categories with different set of results when Category is selected/changed .

How to do this without using JavaScript in Django forms /templates
I couldn’t find a reference to this

Comment: This might help you: https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2018/01/29/how-to-implement-dependent-or-chained-dropdown-list-with-django.html

Comment: You can't do this without javascript.

Comment: Django being so good. I would have loved Django to do this simple thing . Product is live , so I want to minimise code :)

Comment: @T.Tokic Thanks for the reference. I'm looking for django way without javascript. looks like i have no choice but to go with javascript.